# Is there a tool to convert from the brat standoff format to CoNLL-U format?

Tags: natural-language-processing, resource-request

I've been searching for a tool to convert from the [brat standoff format](https://brat.nlplab.org/standoff.html) to the [CoNLL-U format](https://universaldependencies.org/format.html), so that to use it as a parsing corpus model to the [spaCy](https://spacy.io) library.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The brat annotation tool has provided some useful scripts for converting the annotations format including standoff format to CoNLL. Please see this source code from brat GitHub repo for converting the .ann and .txt inputs (standoff format) to .conll file: https://github.com/nlplab/brat/blob/master/tools/anntoconll.py